# Inequality in a triangle with tan

Tags: inequality, triangles

Again, a construction

> Given a triangle $ABC$ with all its angles smaller than $90^\circ$, using standard notations ($\tau$ is the semiperimetr, $r$ the radius of the incircle.), prove that :
>   $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} [(\tan A) ^3 \tan B ] \geq [\frac{2\tau r}{\tau^2-25r^2}]^2$

I post here my solution, hoping for more.

Equivalently, we have to show that $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \frac{(\tan A)^2}{\tan B} \geq [\frac{2\tau r}{\tau^2-25r^2}]\cot A \cot B \cot C $.

From Cauchy-Schwarz, it suffices to show that $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \tan A \geq  [\frac{2\tau r}{\tau^2-25r^2}]\cot A \cot B \cot C$ .

Since, $\cot A \cot B \cot C=\frac{1}{\tan A \tan B \tan C}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \tan A=\tan A \tan B \tan  C$ we just have to prove that $\tan A \tan B \tan C \geq \frac{2\tau r}{\tau^2-25r^2}$.

Finally, it's fairly well-known that $\sin A \sin B \sin C=\frac{\tau r}{2R^2}$ and $\cos A \cos B \cos C=\frac{\tau^2-(2R+r)^2}{4R^2}$ where $R$ is the radius of the circumcircle.

So, it suffices to show that $\frac{2\tau r}{\tau^2-(2R+r)^2} \geq \frac{2\tau r}{\tau^2-25r^2} \Rightarrow R \geq 2r$, which is the well-known Euler inequality.

**Let's see different solutions to this problem, or maybe proofs of the identities used above for $\cos A \cos B \cos C, \sin A \sin B \sin C$**

Comment: You will need something to say about the variables.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Is it ok?

Comment: Dear @math_here Your problem is very interesting, but on this forum it is customary to ask questions with attempts and to give answers. If you want to see a different solutions, so just post yours. Take it in a good spirit.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg OK, I will post my solution in the original thread in a couple of hours (I do not have so much time now). Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I edited it, hope you like it and probably give us a new solution!

Comment: I think it's the best. Only, why your denominator is greater than zero?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg What do you mean, I don't get it